# Graph decomposition into product

Tags: graph-theory, category-theory

I'm working in the [category of *simple graphs*](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/category+of+simple+graphs), where objects are undirected graphs with loops at every vertex and multiple edges are forbidden, and morphisms are *graph morphisms*, that are edge-preserving functions of vertices.

It is well known that decomposition into connected components, e.g. decomposition of $G$ into maximum number of graphs $\{G_i\}$ such that $G = G_1 \sqcup \dotsb \sqcup G_n$, is highly useful, because we can treat $G$ as collection of graphs, so for example we can use *handshake lemma* not on $G$ but on each $G_i$ and so on.

And while categorical definition of coproduct uses generic morphisms, we only need to know that there are *paths* $P_m \hookrightarrow G_i$ with some properties.

So I was wondering:

1. Is there any useful properties of categorical product, known as [*strong product*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strong_product_of_graphs) (if I'm right)?
2. How to simplify it's identification, e.g. what do I need to know about graph $G$ so I can decompose it to form $G \cong G_1 \times G_2$?
3. Is there any other categorical constructions that are useful in terms of graph theory?

Comment: The strong product you refer to in 1. above is not the categorical product. The latter is described under https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tensor_product_of_graphs although I find the wording confusing.

Comment: It is true, yet in this category this definition coincide (note loops at every vertex). More on different categories and products can be found in book Ulrich Knauer: Algebraic Graph Theory Morphisms, Monoids and Matrices

Comment: Sorry, I had misread that part of your question and thought that loops were ruled out. So that is much better, that category has products, coproduct and exponentiation. The latter explains why loops  can (and should) not be avoided. On could also allow loop without  mandating them.